# Working with Area and Length in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I'm currently working on my code, and I have to basically create two new fields in a shapefile (area and length). Then, it requires me to calculate the area and length using Arcpy.UpdateCursor, So far this is what I have (I also had to get the centroid points and print out a list of counties, etc.)

However, some say this is wrong because the code for the length and area are the same, could anyone help figuring out how to improve this code?

```
point_list = []
fc = "MD_County_2014.shp"
field = "COUNTY"
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
for row in cursor:
    print(row.getValue(field))
    point_list.append(arcpy.PointGeometry(row.shape.centroid))   
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(point_list,'test.shp')
    sr_county = arcpy.Describe("MD_County_2014.shp").spatialReference
    arcpy.DefineProjection_management("test.shp",sr_county)    

arcpy.AddField_management(fc, 'area','DOUBLE')
arcpy.AddField_management(fc, 'length','DOUBLE')

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["SHAPE@AREA", "area"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = row[0] / 1E6 
        cursor.updateRow(row)

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["SHAPE@LENGTH", "length"]) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            row[1] = row[0] / 1E6 
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: You appear to have asked the [same question earlier](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/205973/115) and that has now been closed as a duplicate of this. Please do not re-ask the same question. If a question has not been answered then use the edit button to try and improve it instead.

Comment: What are your current shapefile units, and what units are you wanting in your `area` and `length` fields?

Answer (score 3):

Try using `arcpy.CalculateField`

```
import arcpy
fc = "your_feature_class"
expression1 = "!SHAPE.AREA@ACRES!"
expression2 = "!SHAPE.geodesicLength@METERS!"
arcpy.CalculateField(fc, "area_acres", expression1, "PYTHON_9.3")
arcpy.CalculateField(fc, "length_meters", expression2, "PYTHON_9.3")
```

This could be further reduced to:

```
calc = [["area", "!SHAPE.AREA@ACRES!"], ["length", "!SHAPE.geodesicLength@METERS!"]]
for field,expression in calc:
    arcpy.CalculateField(fc,field,expression, "PYTHON_9.3")
```

This assumes you have the fields added, and that you want acres and meters. On the documentation for Calculate field (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field.htm) you have a list of the different units you can specify.

If you wanted to use an update cursor to calculate those values, you could put the two together instead of looping through your data twice:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ['area', 'length', 'SHAPE@']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        area = row[2].getArea('GEODESIC', 'ACRES')
        length = row[2].getLength('GEODESIC', 'METERS')
        row[0] = area
        row[1] = length
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

This could be reduced to:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ['area', 'length', 'SHAPE@']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0],row[1] = [row[2].getArea('GEODESIC', 'ACRES'), row[2].getLength('GEODESIC', 'METERS')]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Check out the documentation on Geometry objects (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/geometry.htm) for other methods, besides `getArea()` and `getLength`